# How to restrict dark mode for a particular Flavor in Android

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

I've an app with multiple flavors supporting dark mode. Each flavor is taking dark theme resources from /main/res directory's drawable-night and values-night folders.

I want to restrict dark mode for a particular app flavor now.

First solution: Each activity to have uiMode in android:configChanges attribute.
Second solution: Removing drawable-night and values-night from /main/res and keeping it to flavors which supports it.

Is there any other solution which could help me restrict dark-mode by few lines of code for a flavor?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current theme and according to that following way u can restrict the dark theme in ur app

```
int currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
switch (currentNightMode) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
        break;
}
```